# How to run Powershell from batch file with normal background colors?

Tags: windows, powershell

When I click the Powershell icon, it comes up with a blue background and a certain look. If I run Powershell from a batch file, it comes up with a black background that looks like cmd.exe. Is there a way to run Powershell from a batch file such that it looks normal rather than like cmd?
I got really close by using start at the beginning. So the batch file is: start powershell -noexit -command "cd 'C:\Myscripts\start path'"
But that creates a Powershell window that is larger with larger font. It just looks stretched out. I just want to double-click on an icon and get a totally normal looking powershell window that ran the specified command when launched.

Answer (score 2):

This *default* color, which you think is normal, is likely changed from this blue background to the same color schema as the Command Prompt.

One reason is the development of [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/), which has it's own [Color Schemes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes?source=recommendations)

Also: [Windows Terminal as your Default Command Line Experience](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-as-your-default-command-line-experience/), which is a setting to start Windows Terminal, on no longer Command Prompt or Powershell, or another terminal app

> Over the course of 2022, we are planning to make Windows Terminal the
> default experience on Windows 11 devices.

P.S. There is a color scheme named [Campbell Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/color-schemes#campbell-powershell), which probably has your favorite color-scheme.